# Angular processing not waiting on http.get .then

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, get

I have a an issue where it seems as though my controller is not waiting on the http.get '.then'. I am getting data properly back but it seems as though another function is processing before the data is retrieved. I've gone through many posts and have tried many of the things mentioned in those posts, but it doesn't seem to help. I am using PHP to retrieve the data.

I have a HTML file that calls two functions (I had tried with one, but when that didn't work, I tried splitting up the functionality).

HTML of the calls

```
<form editable-form name="editableForm" onaftersave="fetch();updateDetailsData()" >
```

Controller functions

```
$scope.fetch = function() {
    $http.get("api/checkSave/"+ JSON.stringify($scope.programDetails))
         .then(function(data) {
              $scope.okToSave = data.data.save;
              $scope.missFields = data.data.fields;
              console.log($scope.okToSave); // line #194
              console.log($scope.missFields); // line #195
        });
}

$scope.updateDetailsData = function(){
    console.log($scope.okToSave); // line #202
}
```

What displays in the console shows:

```
undefined    // line 202
false        // line 194 - correct data
Object       // line 195 - correct data
```

As you can see, it appears to be processing the function updateDetailsData before the fetch function finishes. I thought the then should make processing wait until the get is finished - the promise returned.

I need to do some processing in the updateDetailsData function based on the values in the $scope variables but when it gets there they are undefined.

Can someone help? I'm sure it is something little that I am missing, but I think I have tried just about all solutions provided on these forums and still end up with the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from: `onaftersave="fetch(); updateDetailsData()"`. 
The `update` function executes as soon as `fetch` returns, not as soon as `fetch` is **resolved**.

Rework your function a bit:

```
function fetch () {
    return $http.get("api/checkSave/"+ JSON.stringify($scope.programDetails))
         .then(function(data) {
             // ...     
         });
}

$scope.fetchAndUpdate = function () {
    fetch().then(updateDetailsData);
}
```

In the template:

```
<form editable-form name="editableForm" onaftersave="fetchAndUpdate()">
```

Comment: I get an error trying this saying 'Cannot read property 'then' of undefined'...it does seem to process fetch and updateDetailsData (and in the proper order from what I can see).  The error is on the fetch().then(updateDetailsData) line.

Comment: Did you add the `return` before the `$http` call?

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right, I didn't see that....yes that works and shows everything in right order and only once. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using promises, so you have to wire into them, they aren't blocking:

```
<form editable-form name="editableForm" onaftersave="fetch().then(updateDetailsData)" >
```

Controller functions

```
$scope.fetch = function() {
    return $http.get("api/checkSave/"+ JSON.stringify($scope.programDetails))
         .then(function(data) {
              $scope.okToSave = data.data.save;
              $scope.missFields = data.data.fields;
              console.log($scope.okToSave); // line #194
              console.log($scope.missFields); // line #195
        });
}

$scope.updateDetailsData = function(){
    console.log($scope.okToSave); // line #202
}
```

Comment: this seems to work, but it looks like the functions are called twice. I guess not too much of an issue, since it appears as though the values are being populated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fetch` function is calling `$http.get` which makes an asynchronous call to your server.  What that means is that the call will return right away, it won't block (i.e. stop the code from executing) while it waits for the server to respond.  That is why you provide a callback using the `.then` function.

So taken the way you have currently written it, it is working as designed.  If you want to have `updateDetailsData` function be executed after your `then` code then you have to either put it inside of the then or chain the functions together like Michael P. Bazos or Matthew Berg suggested.